# How to fetch the text from scrolled text widget?

Tags: python, tkinter, textbox

I need to fetch what is entered in `tkinter.scrolledtext.ScrolledText` which is a Textbox. However, `ScrolledText` definition doesn't accept `textvariable` argument. So How can I do it?

Comment: This can be answered by reading documentation or searching this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`textvariable` is not a *must* for widgets to have their text strings manipulated. Below example `get`s the content of the `text` and then puts it in `lbl`'s `text`:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.scrolledtext as tkst

def put_text_in_lbl():
    global text, lbl
    fetched_content = text.get('1.0', 'end-1c')
    lbl['text'] = "What's written in text: " + fetched_content

root = tk.Tk()

text = tkst.ScrolledText(root)
lbl = tk.Label(root)
btn = tk.Button(root, text="Display", command=put_text_in_lbl)

# display
text.pack()
lbl.pack()
btn.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks brother, this solved my issue. But can you please tell me a little about the argumemts you passed in get() function.thanks

Comment: @TusharGautam `'1.0'` means the 0th char in the 1st line, and `'end-1c'` means the 2nd char from the end. `get` returns everything in between. I think text adds newline char automatically as the last, that's why the last char was excluded.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me , when using scrollbar
Wrote a method for getting the value from the scrolledtext
and then updated this value for the label.
this method named for_display was written as a command in button argument.

```py
    import tkinter as tk
    import tkinter.scrolledtext as scrolledtext
    
    def for_dsplyBtn():
        str=txt.get("1.0",'end')
        display["text"]=str
    
    
    window=tk.Tk()
    intro=tk.Label(text="intro")
    intro.pack()
    txt = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(window, undo=True)
    txt['font'] = ('consolas', '12')
    txt.pack(expand=True, fill='both')
    display=tk.Label(window)
    display.pack()
    btn=tk.Button(window,text="Display", command= lambda : for_dsplyBtn())
    btn.pack()
    tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: Maybe a little deeper explanation of what have been done would increase the quality of your post.